# Context.getExternalFilesDirs() and android 7

Tags: android

I want to save a file in SECONDARY STORAGE in app's private space.

```
File[] sdCards = activityInstance.getActivity().getExternalFilesDirs(null);
if (sdCards != null && sdCards.length > 1 && sdCards[1] != null) {
      String savePath = sdCards[1].getAbsolutePath());
     // now check if we can really save file in this dir which should be writable...
     try{
        File testFile = File.createTempFile("test", null, savePath);
        testFile.delete();
     }catch(IOException e){
        // whaat? the "owner" app cannot write in this folder???
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

and now the exception message:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied W/System.err:
>   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
>   W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
>   W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1862)

I must mention this code was working for 2 years and has stopped working on my android 7 (Samsung galaxy S7)....I granted write external storage permission of course (should also work without that permission being granted since it is app's private storage "space")

Comment: What is the value of testFile.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: Permissions should not be needed indeed. But for a test do not only request them in manifest file but also add code to ask the user to confirm the permission at runtime.

Comment: +greenapps - the path is /storage/4A0D-0926/Android/data/com.audioRec/files

Comment: +greenapps - I request permissions from code of course

Comment: ??? So where is "test" ??? The mentioned path is the directory. Not of a file.

Comment: +greenapps - that's the problem, test file cannot be created in the savepath (the above path) because that folder (savePath) is read-only....

Comment: `I request permissions from code of course `. Of course? This follows from `.I granted write external storage permission of course` ?

Comment: I requested write permission (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) from code and I granted that permission (as a user) and run that test cod and I got permission denied (I wanted to specify that everything related with permission was done on my side )

Comment: +greenapps - the problem was manifesting only if the device was plugged in the PC

Comment: Ok. That can happen. You understand why?

Comment: to be honest, only a vague idea. I assume when I plug the phone to the PC, the SD card is also mounted to the PC so the phone has no more write access on that volume

Comment: Yes that can be. But you as user of the device can determine how the device behaves when connecting to PC. As disk or using MTP. Under MTP you have still write access to the sd card.